# COBOL: What is the benefit of using paragraphs and sections instead of subprograms?

Tags: cobol

What is the benefit of using paragraphs and sections for executing pieces of code, instead of using a subprogram instead? As far as I can see paragraphs and sections are dangerous because they have an non intuitive control flow, its easy to fall through and execute stuff you never meant to execute, and there is no variable (item) scoping, therefore it encourages a style of programming where everything is visible to everything else. Its a slippery soup.

I read a lot, but I could not find anything related to the comparative benefit of paragraphs/sections vs a subprogram. I also asked online some people in some COBOL forum, but their answers were along the lines of "is this a joke" or "go learn programming"(!!!).

I do not wish to engage in a discussion of stylistic preferences, everyone writes the way that their brain works, I only want to know, is there any benefit to using paragraphs/sections for flow control? As in, are there any COBOL operations that can be done **only** by using paragraphs/sections? Or is it just a remnant of an early way of thinking about code?

Because no other language I know of has mimicked that, so it either has some mechanical concrete essential reason to exist in COBOL, or it is a stylistic preference of the COBOL people. Can someone illuminate me on what is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are multiple questions... the two most important ones:

## Are there any COBOL operations that can be done only by using paragraphs/sections?

Yes. A likely not complete list:

- `USE` statements in `DECLARATIVES` can only apply to a paragraph or a section. These are used for handling file errors and exceptions. Not all compilers support this COBOL standard feature in full.
- Segmentation (primary: a program that is only partially loaded in memory) is only possible with sections; but that is to be considered a "legacy feature" (at least I don't know of people actually using it this way explicitly); see the [comment of Gilbert Le Blanc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62896806/cobol-what-is-the-benefit-of-using-paragraphs-and-sections-instead-of-subprogra/62897825#comment111228911_62897825) for more details on this
- fall-through, many other languages have this feature with a kind of a `switch` statement (COBOL's `EVALUATE`, which is not the same as a common `switch` but can be used similar has an explicit `break` and no fall-through)
- `GO TO DEPENDING ON` (could be recoded to achieve something similar with `EVALUATE` and then either `PERFORM`, if the paragraphs are *expected* to fall-through, which is not uncommon, then that creates a lot of extra code)
- `GO TO` in general and especially nice - the old obsolete `ALTER` statement
- `PERFORM` statement, format 1 "out-of-line"
- file state is only shared between programs when you define it as `EXTERNAL`, and you often want to have a file state being limited to a single program
- up to COBOL85: `EXIT` statement (plain without anything else, actually doing nothing else then a `CONTINUE` would)

## What is the benefit of using paragraphs and sections for executing pieces of code, instead of using a subprogram instead?

- shared data (I guess you know of programs with `static` data or otherwise (module)global data that is shared between functions/methods and also different source code files)
- much less overhead than a `CALL` is
- consistency:

  - you know what's in your code, you don't know what another program does (or at least: you cannot guarantee that it will do the same some years later exactly the same)
  - easier to extend/change: adding another variable (and also removing part of it, change its size) to a `CALL USING` means that you also have to adjust the called program - and all programs that call this, even when you place the complete definition in a copybook, which is very reasonable, this means you have to recompile all programs that use this
  - a section/paragraph is always available (it is already loaded when the program runs), a `CALL`ed program may not be available or lead to an exception, for example because it cannot be loaded as its parameters have changed
- less stuff to code

Note: While not all compilers support this you can work around nearly all of the runtime overhead and consistency issue when you use one source files with multiple program definitions in (possibly nested) and using a static call-convention. This likely gives you the "modern" view you aim for with scope-limitation of variables, within the programs either persistent (like local-static) when defined in `WORKING-STORAGE` or always passed when in `LINKAGE` or "local-temporary" when in `LOCAL-STORAGE`.

## Should all code of an application be in one program?

[I've added this one to not lead to bad assumptions] Of course not!

Using sub-programs and also user-defined functions (possibly even nested providing the option for "scoped" and "shared" data) is a good thing where you have a "feature boundary" (for example: access to data, user-interface, ...) or with "modern" COBOL where you have a "language boundary" (for example: direct `CALL`s of C/Java/whatever), but it isn't "jut for limiting a counter to a section" - in this case: either define a variable which state is not guaranteed to be available after any `PERFORM` or define one for the section/paragraph; in both cases it would be reasonable to use a prefix telling you this.
Using that "separate by boundary" approach also takes care of the "bad habit of everything being seen by everyone" issue (which is in any case only true for "all sections/paragraphs in the same program).

Personal side note: I would only use paragraphs where it is a "shop/team rule" (it is better to stay consistent then to do things different "just because they are better" [still providing an option to possibly change the common rule]) or for `GO TO`, which I normally not use.
`SECTION`s and `EXIT SECTION` + `EXIT PERFORM [CYCLE]` (and *very rarely* `GOBACK`/`EXIT PROGRAM`) make paragraphs nearly unnecessary.

Comment: Segmenting was important when memory allocation was measured in kilobytes.  I didn't see COBOL segmentation much after 1980.  Alter statements caused a lot of debugging pain in large COBOL programs.  Alter was useful in short, utility programs.  For the OP, the average length of the COBOL programs I worked on was around 10,000 to 20,000 lines.  The entire application was one program.  Usually structured, but not always.  It was the best way of programming with the tools we had in the 1980s.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.
I, and surely many others, view COBOL from the lenses of more recent languages, essentially asking "Why do this instead of x/y/z?". So I am glad I got some explanations.

Most of the points you mentioned can be mitigated by not using GO TO, PERFORM THROUGHs, not using static variables but passing to the programs what they need, using an IDE that does autorefactoring when a program signature changes, and generally using another programming style.

Would it then be fair to say that their only necessary and unavoidable usage is in file error handling?

Comment: > Would it then be fair to say that their only necessary and unavoidable usage is in file error handling? 

possibly, yes, but the "after you did all ...." which includes a lot of tools and a different programming style and still leading to bigger source, binaries and runtime overhead (I know, "modern" people don't mind ;-) is a lot to take and has to be weighted against the benefits.

Answer (score 0):

very short answer. subroutines!!
Subroutines execute in the context of the calling routine. Two virtues: no parameter passing, easy to create. In some languages, subroutines are private to (and are part of) the calling (invoking) routine (see various dialects of BASIC).
direct answer: Section and Paragraph support a different way of thinking about programming. Higher performance than call subprogram. Supports overlays. The "fall thru" aspect can be quite useful, a feature rather than a vice. They may be necessary depending on what you are doing with a specific COBOL compiler.
See also PL/1, BAL/360, architecture 360/370/...

Answer (score 0):

As a veteran Cobol dinosaur, I would say asking about the benefit is not the right question.  I used paragraph (or section) differently than a subprogram.  The right question in my opinion is when to use them logically.  If I can make an analogy, if you have a Dog java class, you will write Dog-appropriate methods within it. If there's a cat involved, you may need a helper class.  In this case the helper class is the subprogram.  Though, you can instead code the helper class methods inside the Dog class, but that will be bad coding.

Answer (score 0):

In any other language I would recommend putting self contained functions into subroutines.

However in COBOL not so much. If the code is very likely to be used in other programs then a subroutine is a good idea. Otherwise not!

The reason being the total lack of any checks on the number type or existence of passed parameters at compile time. Small errors in call statements lead to program crashes at run time. Limiting the use of sub-routines and carefully checking the calling code for errors makes for a more reliable program.

Using paragraphs any type mismatch will be flagged at compile time, or, an automatic conversion will occur.